# android drawable name

Tags: android, drawable

I have an app I am designing and spent about an hour yesterday trying to figure out why 1 of my drawables would not show up. I was finally able to get it to show up by renaming it. It had the file name alc.png which would not show up, I rename it to alcs.png it it worked just fine, however alc1, alc2 and alc3 did not work. Is alc a reserved name in android, and if so what is it? I know it is not a length issue because I have several drawable files with smaller names, ie hs.png.

Just curious it is driving me crazy.

Comment: Please write the code how you have called the drawable element in your application.

Comment: It's an ImageButton so I just used android:src="@drawable/alc" I have 9 other ImageButtons on the page using the same code, only the one named alc didn't work, and if I changed alc to another picture it worked. And once I renamed the alc file to alcs it worked. I also tried cleaning Hassan Samii, and that didn't work. It's not that eclipse wasn't finding it, it showed up in the res folder in the proper place. It wasn't even gining an error, the code compiled no problem it was just when you ran it the picture didn't show up. Like I said I have it working so it's not a bid deal, just curious.

Comment: interesting - have you unzipped the apk and looked if the res is build in?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Like I said there are 9 other images, all png all roughly the same size. All get passed when the apk is completed. The one image just will not show up if you name it alc or alc followed by a number. My only thought was that perhaps the alc name is reserved for something, and that is being used and not the alc file that I added. Like I said I just renamed it alcs and it is working fine now.